# These packages are not recognised in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, wiimote

I have followed a tutorial on how to connect a WiiMote to Ubuntu.
I tried this command.

```bsh
~/$ sudo apt-get install libcwiid1 lswm wmgui wminput
```

And I get this error

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wmgui
E: Unable to locate package wminput
```

I know that these packages exist, I made sure on https://packages.ubuntu.com/, but they don't show up for my release of Ubuntu (20.04).

Is there a way to use older programs for this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my searches on the
[Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/),
package `wmgui` does not exist on 20.04:

---

[image]

---

It exists in the previous version 18.04 or the later 20.10,
but for some reason it does not exist in the 20.04 repository.

You may need to change Ubuntu versions to have this package, or compile it from source.